# keycloak-angular wrong redirect

Tags: angular, keycloak, keycloak-angular

I try to setup Keycloak to protect my angular SPA.

In Keycloak I have setup a realm and two clients (for frontend and backend).

I want all users of the app to be logged in, so I initialize Keycloak with `onLoad: 'login-required'`.

When I load the SPA at localhost:4200 it redirects to the keycloak login page and I can login (I see the session in the keycloak admin console).

The problem:
After logging in, I am **redirected to `https://localhost:4200` instead of `http://localhost:4200`**.

I don't set anything to https. Also the valid redirect url is set to http://localhost:4200

The only difference to all the tutorials I have compared my code to is, that I use a remote keycloak server to test (not a local keycloak instance). The remote keycloak instance is called via https.

```
{
  config: {
    url: 'https://auth.mydomain.com',
    realm: 'mydomain.com',
    clientId: 'frontend'
  },
  initOptions: {
    onLoad: 'login-required'
  }
}
```

I just tried with a local keycloak instance and my configured redirect works here.

**Is there a way to use the remote keycloak instance without it changing my redirect path to https?**

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem.

In my case the reverse-proxy (nginx) in front of the keycloak server had the following configuration

```
proxy_redirect          http:// https://;
```

With this line, nginx replace all occurrences of 'http://' with 'https://'
*"in the “Location” and “Refresh” header fields of a proxied server"* [[nginx docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_redirect)]